# How to correct error CS0122: 'WebHost' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing, visual-studio-code

i'm currently trying to do integration testing on a asp.net application which i'm developing in Visual Studio Code in C#.

Since i'm very new to integration testing i was trying to follow a tutorial or some steps another person had taken to do the same, so i started following this tutorial, https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/writing-integration-tests-in-aspnet-core-using-xunit.
In this tutorial it is explained that a necessary step to the integration tests is to define a setup class for booting up the ASP.NET test server along with the necessary settings to be passed and they do that by overriding the default WebApplicationFactory class and providing our own implementation of the WebHostBuilder method.

And they do it like this:

```
public class MyReaderApiAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

So i tried to mimic what they did like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using DDDSample1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

public class TripApiAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

This is the class i have in my program now, and so i basically only switched the name of the class from their class and added some packages that were needed. And now when i try to run dotnet build on my project this error appears:

```
C:\Users\berna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Informática\3ºano - Informática\Arqsi\Projecto\projeto_integrador_grupo67\mdv\Tests\IntegrationTests\TripApiAppFactory.cs(10,10): 
error CS0122: 'WebHost' is inaccessible due to its protection level [C:\Users\berna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Informática\3ºano - Informática\Arqsi\Projecto\projeto_integrador_grupo67\mdv\DDDNetCore.csproj]
```

Can someone explain me if i can fix this error and if so how? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Also if someone has any advice on how to do integration testing, more precisely on .net app developed in C# on VSCode that would be great too.

Thank you in advance for any kind of comment, help or feedback you might give.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the property `WebHost` in the derived class, even though that property is private member of the base class, and therefore cannot be accessed in derived classes.

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-webapplicationfactory), that is what Microsoft has to say about it.